# find way to turn rotater class dynamiccaly according to number of inputs

Tags: css, dynamic, sass, rotation

how to generalize div position (https://codepen.io/suez/pen/vAais) so that, if I put in fewer elements, they adjust to its symmetric position => n/360 degrees of difference between them.

any idea how to modify this piece?

```
$numOfElems: 8;

@for $i from 1 through $numOfElems {
  $deg: 360deg / $numOfElems;
  .rotater:nth-child(#{$i}) {
    transform: rotate($deg/-2 + $deg * ($i - 1));
  }

  .menu.active {
    .rotater:nth-child(#{$i}) .btn-icon {
      transform: translateY(-10em) rotate($deg/2 - $deg * ($i - 1)); 
    }
  }
}
```

to clarify with a pic:

[image]

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to figure out a way to do this dynamically without needing to set the $numOfElems variable in the SCSS? I'm not sure that's possible with such a complicated graphical arrangement. Normally you can use `display: flex` to dynamically size content in a container based on the number of children, but I can't imagine configuring that to work in a circle or ring.

Comment: The only thing that comes to mind is rewriting that SCSS loop to work in JavaScript and insert style into the document based on the number of elements. Seems like overkill, though.

Comment: added a picture to clarify